# TypeScript type for a compare function's parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am declaring a function to use on a `sort` method that takes the value on an array of objects and compares it against another array of objects

```
const compare = (a, b) => {
  let x = 0
  let y = 0
  RoleIndex.forEach(({ role, id}) => {
    if (role.includes(a.role)) x = id
    if (role.includes(b.role)) y = id
  })

  if (x > y) return 1
  else return -1
})
```

But I am doing this on TypeScript, I am quite new at TypeScript but I can not believe I have to declare the parameters this way:

```
const compare = ((a: { role: string}, b: { role: string}) => {
  let x: number = 0
  let y: number = 0
  RoleIndex.forEach(({ role, id}) => {
    if (role.includes(a.role)) x = id
    if (role.includes(b.role)) y = id
  })

  if (x > y) return 1
  else return -1
})
```

Is there a simpler way?

Here is the whole code of what I am trying to do:

[TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/gWoXPw)

Comment: What is the type of `RoleIndex`? If that's an existing type, you can do `(a: RoleType, b: RoleType)`.

Comment: They have different values, `RoleIndex` has `positions` and `value` and the array I am comparing has `id` and `role`, but  I guess I could make a type for compare too and use your shorthand

Comment: Please consider modifying this code to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/KN7YrW) where the only issues present are the ones you're asking about. You should include the array you're trying to sort also, since it presumably already has elements of the right type. There are a number of different ways to specify the types of `a` and `b`, one of which is to annotate them with anonymous object types as you've done.  I could say more but without a [mcve] I'm not inclined to go into detail.

Comment: you can also do `<T extends { role: string; id: number }>(a: T, b: T)`, but if you use that type a lot around your codebase just make a separate type for it

Comment: On a different note, you're *mutating* the things you're sorting?  I'd be concerned about that if I saw that in a code review.

Comment: @jcalz I added the link to the playground

Comment: In that playground link I see that you are calling `array.sort(compare)` but `array`'s elements have no `id` property, which is required by `compare`. Is *that* the issue you're asking about?   The point of a [mcve] is to highlight and demonstrate a specific issue; if people who want to help you are spending time looking at extraneous problems, there's a lower chance of getting an answer that helps you.

Comment: @jcalz Yes I fixed that as I have removed the mutation

Comment: So, uh, what do you want to see here?  If you define `compare` calback inline in the `sort()` function instead of beforehand, its params will be inferred.  Honestly with the code you've presented I'd refactor to something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/kNr1Vw) so that I'm not looking up the role `id` over and over again for each entry.

Comment: @jcalz, thanks! The end goal really is to reorder the initial array according to the roles on `RoleIndex` it's just that you came with a much better way of doing it, even thou I did not really wanted to mutate the original array, nice to know that the types can be inferred if inlined.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment responses.

[@Chase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10305477/chase) pointed out there is a shorthand I could use `const compare<T extends { role: string }>(a: T, b: T) =>...`

But more importantly [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) pointed out I was mutating the original `array` which I did not notice, with the `sort` method.

[@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) also refactored the code in a much more functional way, and pointed out that if the `sort` method is inline their parameters types are inferred. So this a much better approach. Not only I don't have to declare the types but is not mutating the original array and it's a lot more readable.

In the end I used [@jcalz approach](https://tsplay.dev/kNr1Vw) and did this

```
const sortedArray = array
  .map(employee => ({
    ...employee,
    id: RoleIndex.find(({ role }) => role.includes(employee.role)) ?. id ?? 100
  }))
  .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/VNVGGm)